How can a subtype of number not be a number?
async function someFunction<T extends number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const result: number = await fn();
    return result;   //Nope
}

async function otherFunction(fn: () => number): Promise<number> {
    const result: number = await fn();
    return result; // ALL good
}

Playground

Promise<42> extends Promise<number> but it's not any number, it's only 42 Playground

This question involves Promise<Promise<number>>, not Promise<number>. Those are, unfortunately, different things entirely, although you'll be hard-pressed to find a Promise<Promise<number>> at runtime.  Could you [edit] this question so that it doesn't seem to nest promises unless that's what you're asking about?  Maybe by switching it to this version if you agree it demonstrates the same basic issue?

The bottom line here is that when you do:
async function someFunction<T extends number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    const result: number = await fn();
    return result;   //Nope
}

you are forcing something that is of type T which extends number to become a number but then you are trying to downcast it again to T.
Consider this other possibility:
async function doubleMe<T extends number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {    
    const result: number = (await fn())*2; 
    return result; // Problem, you passed T in are trying to get 2*T out
}
doubleMe<42>(async () => 42); 

Here someone called doubleMe expecting a 42 back but got a 84 instead without knowing it because the signature does not reflect it (if TypeScript actually allowed it)
These however will work:
async function someFunction<T extends number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<number> {    
    const result: number = (await fn())*2; 
    return result; 
}

this one reflects the fact that you upcasted the result.
async function someFunction<T extends number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {    
    const result2: T = await fn(); 
    return result2; 
}

this retains T as the result of the function
TypeScript here is warning you that the function may be called with a T that is not any number.

A subtype of number is a number but you return a number instead of its subtype.
The error message is:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'number' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'number'.(2322)

So converting T to number is a bad idea:
Playground
class MyNumber extends Number{
    show(){
        alert(this);
    }
}

async function someFunction<T extends Number>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<ReturnType<typeof fn>> {
    const a: Number = await fn();
    return Number(a);
}

(async()=>{
  const a = await someFunction(async () => new MyNumber(42));
  console.log(a);
  a.show(); // doesn't exits;
})();


"converting T to number is a bad idea" - no it's not, it's the other direction that's problematic. Also why does your example use Number instead of number? Number objects are generally considered a bad idea.

@Bergi this is a real example what happens when you return base type, it's totally valid, my guess you misunderstood what i wanted to demonstrate.

I did understand what you wanted to demonstrate, I just think that extending Number is a bad idea in general and no less in a demo example. Also the first criticism still stands.
